# Persistent Store data lost after session terminates in Blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, java-me, store, persistent

I am using persistent stores to store data in a Blackberry application.
While I create objects and store it in persistent store in same session data is saved properly.
But the data is not recovered from store in next session.

How do I fix this?

My code is as follows:

```
static TrialStore ts = new TrialStore();
static Vector data= new Vector();

synchronized (store) {

store.setContents(data);

ts = new TrialStore();

ts .setElement(TrialStore.USERNAME, username);
ts .setElement(TrialStore.PASSWORD, password);

data.addElement(ts);

store.commit();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `PersistentStore` class to get and store the persistable object, for example:

```
Vector data = (Vector) PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(KEY).getContents();
```

Once you have updated the data, you can store it using:

```
PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(KEY).setContents(data);
PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(KEY).commit();
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, my problem solved with above answer. 
getContents() was missing on my side before setContents()...my silly mistake. Thanks again